POWERSHELL CommentHelp: cannot access .OUTPUTS and .NOTES in function-CommentHelp
I'm on WINDOWS 10 and use POWERSHELL 7.4.2.
My script writes documentation-files for each module-script (.psm1) as Markdown-files (.md). I can get access with Get-Help to every commentHelp-keyword but OUTPUT and NOTES.
This is how I get access to the commentHelp-sections of a module-file:
# extract AST from source-file
$tokens = §null
$errors = $null
$ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($sourceFile, [ref]$tokens, [ref]$errors)

# get data of all functions in file
$functionDefinitions = $ast.FindAll( {
    param([System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast] $ast)
    $ast -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst] -and ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 5 -or $ast.Parent -isnot [System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionMemberAst])
}, $true)

I can access the keywords in the commentHelp of each function (.SYNOPSIS, .DESCRIPTION, .PARAMETER, .EXAMPLE ...) by the Get-Help command
$functionDescription = (Get-Help -Name $functionDefinition.Name).Description

where $functionDefinition.Name is the object with the commentHelp-content of a single function.
$examples = Get-Help -Name $FunctionDefinition.Name -Examples

gives me the object with all examples.
Looking at the commentHelp-object with
$functionDescription | format-list

displays all commentHelp-keywords and their values properly. The values of OUTPUTS, NOTES and ROLE are present as strings. But the Get-Help commands for OUTPUTS and NOTES deliver a null-value, ROLE works fine.
There are no execution-errors when parsing the commentHelp, just no values for OUTPUTS and NOTES.
Is there anything special with OUTPUTS and NOTES? Does anyone have a solution for this issue?
Peace and keep healthy

Did you try : (Get-Help -Name $functionDefinition.Name).Description

My wishful thinking: a comment-base help based on markdown (or even: any comment to support colored markdown). Unfortunately that isn't the case and the existing comment-base help parsers (as platyPS) are quite limited (indeed no OUTPUTS and NOTES), therefore I also wrote my own convertor:  Get-MarkdownHelp

@iRon, this meets my intention. I finally decided to make a home-grown markdown-script because of the many problems I had with pLatsyPS and similar software.Thank you for sharing your code. Peace.

I have worked on the same problem. Here is my solution.
Notes is actually in the alertSet property while Output is in the returnValues property. They can also be arrays and sometimes the first item in the array is an empty string which PowerShell displays for you automatically if you don't iterate through the array, so, it might appear there is no data in that property.
Here is my implementation:

Get-Note.ps1
Get-Output.ps1
Get-HelpCommandData.ps1

Don't ask me why I wrote the module this way. It was a phase.
Here's an example usage:
cdhunt/httpunitPS/build.ps1
Which generates https://github.com/cdhunt/httpunitPS/tree/main/docs.

Man, this is great, thank you so much. It solved my problems. Thank you again.
